# Best Practices for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I develop various things on firebase such as chat, media storage and so on for many clients. My question is, which one is the best? One Firebase project per client or one project for all customers separated by nodes.

For paid accounts, is there a limit to projects?

Comment: If they are independent projects, why use a single Firebase project? The instances in which you may use the same Firebase  project for different apps may be limited to making an administrators app and a general use app, for all other cases, if it is not required that you use the same data for different clients, don't try it

Comment: They are the same projects with different clients

Comment: "For paid accounts, is there a limit to projects?" There is no limit to the number of paid projects an account can have.

Comment: "They are the same projects with different clients " popular ethics demand that you put in the same effort to make distinct projects for as many people who are willing to pay for your services, that is if you did not make it known to them that you are selling such a pre built project. Of course you can use the same code (heck, I even do that quite often), but the databases should preferably be distinct to avoid the future complexity of a change in one client's app affecting all the others